# Is it okay to "edit" questions just to look at the MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax

I'm pretty new to MathJax, and one way I've been trying to learn is to click on "edit" for posts that use features I would like to learn.  Then I just click "cancel."  The last time I did this, I got a notice that my previous edit was rejected.  The last time I intentionally edited a question, I know it was accepted, because I got 2 points or something like that, so I know this is something else.

Am I violating some rule, or did I just forget to click "Cancel"?

Comment: Which edits are you referring to? There's [six](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/235128/saulspatz?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) of them.

Comment: @JohnMa I don't care about the edits or the rejections themselves.  Am I getting a message today because an edit was rejected last week sometime?  I just want to know if it's OK to continue clicking "edit" just to look at the MathJax source, with no intention of editing the question.

Comment: What I mean is that I cannot find what you described in your history. You said you did not change anything but still got a rejection. However I cannot find this instance in your edit history. Sorry I am just confused.

Comment: @JohnMa Oh I see.  What I meant was, while looking at the MathJax, I saw a notice at the top of the screen that said my previous edit had been rejected.  Maybe it's been there every time I've looked at the MathJax since that edit was rejected, and I simply haven't noticed -- that sounds like me.  As I explained in my comment to quid's answer below, I didn't even think of that as a rejection, and had forgotten all about it.  Thanks for you help, but quid's cleared the matter up for me.

Comment: I peek at the MathJax in questions all the time (though I usually remember to click Cancel).

Comment: To be honest I do the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I do not see any problem in doing what you do.

The warning is just because you had an actual [rejection of a suggested edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/946758). 
But this was just bad luck; the edit itself seemed to make sense, so I assume it was intentional and not a by product of your practice. Maybe you just forgot about that one.

That said, if you "right-click" (or whatever is the equivalent action in your setup) on a formula, you get a menu and there you can select "show math as" and then TeX Commands. This often may be a more direct way to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the "right-click" suggestion.  That will come in very handy.  I did have a couple of edits rejected because someone got there first, and I don't even think of them as rejections.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But the system does not distinguish for the warning (though maybe it should).

Comment: A remark: The "right-click" method works great if you are only interested in the MathJax part. I also often use the "edit" method if I want to quote sections that involve both MathJax code an text.

Comment: @StefanMesken yes, that's true. Also one might be interested how some text formatting using Markdown is done.

Answer (score 2):

To be explicitly clear, there's no rule against doing this.

And clicking "edit" by itself doesn't have any effect on the post at all, and is not recorded anywhere (except in a server log somewhere that, in practice, nobody is likely to look at). So even if there were a rule against it, there would be no way for anyone on the site to find out that you broke that rule.